# Awk inside expect

Tags: linux, bash, awk, expect

I'm having errors when sending this to expect

```
send "someagent_id=`ps aux | grep someagent| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`\r"
```

Error:

```
can't read "2": no such variable
    while executing
"send "someagent_id=`ps aux | grep someagent| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`\r""
```

Comment: Do you really need a `grep -v grep`  ?.. i don't see much difference not using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is the PID for some process, you don't need all this messy thing: <strike>`ps aux | grep someagent| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`</strike>.

You can get a process PID just with [`pgrep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/pgrep.1.html):

In your case it would be:

```
send "someagent_id=$(pgrep SOMEAGENT)\r"
```

Comment: By the way, what if I grep then 2 pid shows? how can I eliminate the second one (which I think is just the pgrep process).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   someagent_id=$(ps aux | grep someagent| grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'\r)
   send $someagent_id
```

`` --> previous version 
$ --> new version. Both do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
send "someagent_id=`ps aux | grep someagent| grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}'`\r"
```

and maybe better with this 1 pipe only version

```
send "someagent_id=`ps aux | awk '/someagent/ && ! /awk/ {print \$2}'`\r"
```

Answer (score 0):

With ps options

```
 ps -C someagent -o pid=

 send "someagent_id=$(ps -C someagent -o pid=)"
```